# A question on rotation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

> Question: A spool of mass $M$  and radius $2r$ lies on an inclined plane. a light thread is wound around the connecting tube of the spool (radius of connecting tube is $r$)   and its free end carries a weight of mass $m$. The value of $m$ so that the system is in equilibrium is________________.

my approach to this problem is to first equate the the tension and weight of the block and the free end because the question asks for equllibrium.

T=mg

now for the spool ,for equilibrium of the spool the net torque should be zero . My question here
about which point should we take the net torque to be zero . Is it about the center of mass or the point of contact?

if i understand this , i can simply equate the torques and get the answer.

Comment: It doesn't matter.   The location of the origin is arbitrary.    In some problems it's easier to choose the origin at a point of contact of force so that the torque due to that force is zero.

Comment: When i take center of mass as the point then the torque due to mgsin(there) is 0 as it passes through the center of mass. Torque applied by the string is Tr= mgr. Now for equilibrium I have to equate these torques but i get mgr= 0. Can you tell what is the mistake that I am making .

Comment: If you take center of mass as the point, friction force will apply torque in the opposite direction

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer is both**

If the net torque around point of contact was nonzero, the spool would rotate upward or downward => no equilibrium. If the net torque was not zero around center of mass, the spool would start rotating around its own axis and...

You can imagine and determine what happens when you add mass **dm** on top of load of mass **m** or when we increase the mass of the spool by **dM**, assuming the tread is massless. I tried it and found that

So for equilibrium to happen, torque around both of them must be zero.

**So you can benefit from any of them, I would choose the contact axis in this case**

**Edit: More detail**

Firstly, this equilibrium would not be possible without friction force between spool and inclined plane and between thread and connecting tube. Or we can imagine that one end of the thread is connected (fixed) to spool.

Now imagine that you put small mass **dm** on top of **m**, now the load tries to increase the length of the available thread => for that to happen the spool must rotate.

If the load tried to make the spool rotate in the same direction as the friction force did (i.e. torque directions were same), the equilibrium would not be possible so it does not make sense => ignore this case.

Assume the total mass of the spool does not change if a small amount of thread (length *dl*) is freed from it, and we can assume the friction force (between spool and the inclined plane) is less than its maximum possible magnitude (from the logic of the problem) which is directly proportional to **M** => when we put **dm** on top of **m** the friction force between spool and the inclined plane can be assumed to be less than the maximum possible value as before. Assume the static and dynamic coefficients of friction are the same.

Amount of torque around point of contact will be not zero but **dm*g*3r** at that instant and amount of torque with respect to the center of mass will be **dm*g*r** (because of equilibrium), it means in our ideal case it starts accelerating upward by rotation without any sliding.

If the mass of the spool is increased by a small amount, ideally it will start rotating downwards without any slip.

The reason why I would choose the contact point is to decrease number of equations.

1) If I use the contact point

```
         T * 3r = Mgsin(angle)*r and we know T
```

2) If I use center of mass

```
         friction * 2r = T * r 

         Mgsin(angle) - friction = T
```

The same answer with less number of equations

Comment: "whenever you increase the load => center of mass axis will dominate whenever you increase mass of the spool => the contact axis will be the answer". I haven't understood what you are trying to say in this paragraph. Could you please elaborate on this. And also why did you choose contact axis in this case?

Comment: @lamedeb, I will clarify it by editing the question

Comment: But in real world, if there is difference between coefficients of static and dynamic friction forces, and equilibrium friction force is somewhere in between their maximum values, if enough mass is added to the load, the spool starts sliding down by rotating backward (as it was trying to climb). So, because of rapid decrease in friction force (which is applied from the point of contact), torque with respect to the center of mass increases rapidly, that is what I mean by saying "whenever you increase the load => center of mass axis will dominate".

Comment: When we do the same thing for the spool in this particular case again the same thing happens but relatively smaller. But they don't make sense, they are my intuition only, so I removed them now.